# Multiple level eager loading in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

Let's say I have these relationships

```
class Invitation
{
    public function invitedPeople()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Person', 'personID');
    }
}

class Person 
{
    public function apartments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Apartment', 'apartment_person', 'personID', 'apartmentID');        
    }
}

class Apartment 
{
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City', 'cityID');
    }
}
```

My question here is, how many nested levels can we have when using Laravel eager loading?
I've tried this query and it's not working, can someone suggest a work around for this?

```
return Invitation::with(['invitedPeople', 'invitedPeople.apartments', 'invitedPeople.apartments.city'])
```

Comment: You can nest as many levels as you want. Define "not working", as that should work fine. The only thing I see is that you did not call `->get()` at the end.

Comment: There is no limit but you can optimize this by doing `Invitation::with(['invitedPeople.apartments.city'])`.

Comment: @user3158900 Invitation::with('invitedPeople.apartments.city']) would do three joins including invitedPeople, apartments and city?

Comment: Yes and no.  It doesn't use joins, but it would eager load all the data you need.

Answer (score 10):

Change it to

```
 return Invitation::with('invitedPeople.apartments.city')->get()
```

It will eager load all the related data for you. You missed the get() function. You can nest as deep as it can go.